# NWMLS IDX PHP script?

Tags: php, xml, rets

I currently use [PHRETS](https://github.com/troydavisson/PHRETS) to query/download information from the RMLS's RETS server. I've tried a few different configs and haven't been able to get it to work. I also don't know if *PHRETS* can already do what I want?

I was wondering if there's a similar script or library for connecting to the NWMLS IDX server? A PHP script/library would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer but maybe it'll help somebody later.

Here's a link to a [list of RETS clients](http://www.reso.org/tools) "supported" by RESO the Standards Organization for Real Estate.

Not on this list but for PHP there's also [VieleRETS](https://github.com/dkullmann/vielerets)